# revert chmod 777 / -R

Tags: chmod, directory, recursive

while executing a command i made a mistake and executed (ubuntu 10)

sudo chmod 777 / -R               # okay you may laugh

now all my filesystem has 777 permitions , obviously i dont know which where the permitions for every folder and file in my 1TB drive  :D

is there anyway i can revert this ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Which particular OS?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/141806/chmod-r-777-on-ubuntu-numerous-problems

Comment: Finaly i recover my data booting in recovery mode...

Answer (score 4):

Wow... that's pretty bad...  The best thing you can do now is back up your personal data and reinstall your system.

Since that's probably not what you wanted to hear, the second best (and probably substantially more painful) thing to do is something like:

```
for package in `dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'`; do
    apt-get install --reinstall $package
done
```

Note that this fix is purely theoretical (I've never tried it), but it will reinstall every package on your system (because as far as I can tell `apt` and `dpkg` don't have a "fix permissions" function like RPM).  Reinstalling should fix the permissions on all the files that are in packages.

This "fix" *may* break other things, and you will probably still have some 777'd files floating around that ***aren't*** part of any packages, so you should follow up by `find`ing all the stuff that's mode 777 and making sure the list looks sane.

Comment: See also the question Cakemox pointed to in their comment above (http://serverfault.com/questions/141806/)... looks like the same advice can be found there.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command

```
rpm --setperms $(rpm -qa)
```

This will reset all permissions to the defaults stored in the rpm database.

Or, if you want to go package by package and get some more output, try:

```
for p in $(rpm -qa) ; do echo "$p" ; rpm --setperms $p ; done
```

This will *only* revert files installed with rpm, not other files you created manually, or in your /home or installed in another way other than as an rpm package.

If you have a full backup, then you can get the permissions from there.

Comment: `rpm` on Ubuntu?

Comment: ups, sorry, was too fast. Doesn't apt have a similar option? Forgot that Ubuntu was debian based, sorry.