# chmod -R 777 /. - RHEL 5.5

Tags: rhel5, file-permissions, chmod, server-crashes

A shell script testing went bad and it issued

```
chmod -R 777 /.
```

to the system, instead of

```
chmod -R 777 ./
```

and as expected it wiped the critical meta data. We have turned off the system and it will not function properly the next time it is turned on.

I am told that

```
rpm --setperms -a 

rpm --setugids -a
```

should atleast fix the permission of the packages maintained by rpm. Is it worth doing?

And is there any script available which will copy the permission from an identical system? To atleast get the box working. The Box is running RHEL5.5

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [revert chmod 777 / -R](http://serverfault.com/questions/233764/revert-chmod-777-r)

Comment: @GraemeDonaldson Yes, but I am getting verified a possible solution and my platform is different. Just in case it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your duplicate system is truly duplicate then you may have a chance with running

```
getfacl -R . >perms.bak
```

on the good system in / and then on the bad one

```
setfacl --restore=perms.bak
```

Comment: Well, I plan to make a new RHEL 5.5 box and then do the above procedures, that should fix the out of box packages, right?